# Everything changes back when i hit enter (javascript and html)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a fiddle:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2NFV7/)**

And here is my code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Add Players</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background: #414141;
        }

        #players{
            background: #87828A;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        .player{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .playersquare{
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .score{
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var players = {
            playerCount : 1,
            player1 : {
                active: false,
                name : '',
                score : 0,
            },
            player2 : {
                active: false,
                name : '',
                score : 0,
            },
            player3 : {
                active: false,
                name : '',
                score : 0,
            },
            player4 : {
                active: false,
                name : '',
                score : 0,
            },
        }

        function addPlayer(){
            var name = document.getElementById('playerName').value

            if (name == ''){
                alert('You have not entered anything in the name box!')
            }
            else if(players.playerCount <= 4){
                var curPlayer = 'player' + players.playerCount
                players[curPlayer].name = name;
                players[curPlayer].active = true;
                players.playerCount++
            }

            updatePlayers()
        }

        function updatePlayers(){
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                if (players['player' + i].active){
                    $('#player' + i).fadeIn('slow')
                }
                else{
                    $('#player' + i).fadeOut('slow')
                }

                document.getElementById('player'+i+'name').innerHTML = players['player' + i].name
                document.getElementById('player'+i+'score').innerHTML = players['player' + i].score
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="players" style="float: left;">

        <div class="player" id="player1" style="display: none">
            <div class="playersquare" style="background: green"></div>
            <span class="playerName" id="player1name">Player</span>
            <span class="score" id="player1score">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="player" id="player2" style="display: none">
            <div class="playersquare" style="background: red"></div>
            <span class="playerName" id="player2name">Player</span>
            <span class="score" id="player2score">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="player" id="player3" style="display: none">
            <div class="playersquare" style="background: blue"></div>
            <span class="playerName" id="player3name">Player</span>
            <span class="score" id="player3score">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="player" id="player4" style="display: none">
            <div class="playersquare" style="background: yellow"></div>
            <span class="playerName" id="player4name">Player</span>
            <span class="score" id="player4score">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form action="" method="">
        <input type="text" id="playerName"/>
        <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addPlayer()"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why, but if I add some players, and then go to add another one, but hit enter while the text box is selected, everything vanishes. Why is that?

I am still sort of new to JS, so i don't even know where to start looking for an answer

Comment: You're submitting the form (default behavior for pressing enter inside a form, for some browsers/scenarios), and therefore the page is reloading (since the action is `""`, which is the current page)

Comment: To stop this, you can either remove the <form> wrapper or use onsubmit in the form and return false. `<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return false;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit enter the textfield parent `form` action attribute gets triggered & since `actions=""` is empty nothing really happens except you loose the page you were on.

You can do the following to fix this:

- Add this `onSubmit="return false;"` in your form tag, like this:

  ```
  <form action="" method="" onSubmit="return false;">
  ```
- But if you want to do something else on `onSubmit` but don't want the enter key from doing it use this script:

  ```
  $('#formid').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
      if (code  == 13) {               
      e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I figured it out, i added onSubmit="return false;" into my form tag and that seemed to fix it

Comment: ahan nice adding it in my answers incase some one else had same issue.